# How to write a 'c like if' parser with boost spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

I want to write a rule that parses something like:
if (1==1) {do something}
My problem is how to 'disable' a semantic action bases on the result of another rule's output.
For demonstration in my example I use a int_ parser  and simply use that value as its result. I want to bypass that action if the ifrule returns false.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

int main() {
    qi::symbols<char, std::function<bool(int, int)>> sym;
    sym.add
    ("==", std::equal_to<>())
    ("!=", std::not_equal_to<>());

    using namespace qi::labels;
    int result;
    auto bin_eval = [](auto const& lhs, auto const& op, auto const& rhs) {
        return op(lhs, rhs);
    };

    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, bool(), qi::space_type> ifrule;
    ifrule = (qi::lit("if") >> '(' >> qi::int_ >> sym >> qi::int_ >> ')')
            [qi::_val = px::bind(bin_eval, _1, _2, _3)];
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, int(), qi::space_type> rule;
    rule = ifrule >> '{' >> qi::int_[_val = _1] >> '}';

    for (std::string const s : {"if (1==2) {1}", "if (1==1) {1}"}) {
        std::cout << std::quoted(s) << " -> ";

        if (qi::phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), rule, qi::space, result)) {
            std::cout << "result: " << std::boolalpha << result << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "parse failed\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your grammar an expression grammar or a statement parser? What should be the value of `result` if the condition is false?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for shortcut evaluation?

If so, there is literally nothing you have to do to get that effect, nor is there anything you COULD do, short of modifying the input.

As long as you are combining the parsing and the evaluation, you will necessarily be visiting the entire expression tree (because you have to parse it).

Only if you pruduce an AST tree you could do optimizations:

- static optimizations that simplify the tree (removing double negations, removing tautologies, resolving contradictions like `x xor not x -> not (x and not x) -> not (false) -> true`

  This is a rich topic and not as easy as it seems (see e.g. [Boost Spirit: parse boolean expression and reduce to canonical normal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387155/boost-spirit-parse-boolean-expression-and-reduce-to-canonical-normal-form/60405247#60405247))
- runtime optimization, this is where shortcut evaluation comes in. E.g. `a && (b | (c ^ d) | (!a & (b ^ c))) would be
  [![enter image description here][1]][1]. If`a`is false, the entire evaluation can be skipped because the result will be`false`.

---

> Is your grammar an expression grammar or a statement parser? What should be the value of `result` if the condition is false?  – [sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe) [just now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325564/how-to-write-a-c-like-if-parser-with-boost-spirit#comment110231776_62325564)

Assuming the answer is "expression" not "statement" then this is arguably just an expression parser with some binary operators and one ternary (with implicit else branch).

In that case you could cheat and just return an optional value.

I'll show you a more complete AST-based example because likely you're trying to parse something less trivial than what you're showing anyways.

### An AST

As always, think of what your Abstract Syntax Tree looks like fist:

```
namespace Ast {

    struct BinOp;
    struct Conditioinal;

    using Expr = boost::variant<
        int,
        bool,
        BinOp,
        Conditional
    >;

    struct BinOp {
        BinOpF op;
        Expr lhs, rhs;
    };

    struct Conditional {
        Expr condition, true_part;
    };
}
```

I've taken the function definition for operators from your code:

```
using BinOpF = std::function<bool(int, int)>;
```

The variant wouldn't actually compiler with the recursive use incomplete types, so let's use the wrapper:

```
using Expr = boost::variant<
    int,
    bool,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<BinOp>,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<Conditional>
>;
```

### Parsing

The parser construction is usually a 1:1 mapping of rules:

```
    expr
        = '(' >> expr >> ')'
        | conditional_
        | int_ 
        | bool_ 
        | binop_
        ;
```

Let's put it in a grammar (that also hides the skipper).

> Note I also shuffled the binop parser around splitting `expr_` into `simple_` and using semantic actions to create the `BinOp` Ast nodes for efficiency. This stems from experience that grammars get horrifically inefficient with backtracking otherwise.

```
template <typename It>
struct Expr : qi::grammar<It, Ast::Expr()> {
    Expr() : Expr::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;
        start = qi::skip(space) [ expr_ ];

        simple_
            = '(' >> expr_ >> ')'
            | conditional_
            | int_ 
            | bool_ 
            ;

        auto make_bin = [](auto lhs, auto op, auto rhs) {
            return Ast::BinOp { op, lhs, rhs };
        };

        expr_ %= simple_
            >> *(binop_ >> expr_) [ _val = px::bind(make_bin, _val, _1, _2) ];
            ;

        conditional_
            = lexeme["if"] 
            >> '(' >> expr_ >> ')' 
            >> '{' >> expr_ >> '}'
            ;

        binop_.add
            ("==", std::equal_to<>())
            ("!=", std::not_equal_to<>());

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(expr_)(conditional_))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Expr()> start;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Expr(), qi::space_type> simple_, expr_;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Conditional(), qi::space_type> conditional_;

    qi::symbols<char, Ast::BinOpF> binop_;
};
```

That's it. Note that it will parse a multitude of expressions that your parser could not, previously. E.g.:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc2b8a9b4cfb6757)**

```
int main() {
    Expr<std::string::const_iterator> const parser;

    for (std::string const s : {
        "false",
        "1==2",
        "-3!=3",
        "if (true) {42}",
        "if (false) {43}",
        "if (1==2) {44}",
        "if (false == (1 == 2)) {  ((((45)))) }",
        "if (false == (1 == 2)) { if (true) {46} }",
        "if (true == (1 == 2)) {47} else { 48 };",
    }) {
        std::cout << std::quoted(s) << " -> ";

        auto f = begin(s);
        auto l = end(s);
        Ast::Expr expr;
        if (qi::parse(f, l, parser, expr)) {
            std::cout << "result: " << expr << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f!=l) {
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"false" -> result: 0
"1==2" -> result: (1 (opfun) 2)
"-3!=3" -> result: (-3 (opfun) 3)
"if (true) {42}" -> result: if(1) {42}
"if (false) {43}" -> result: if(0) {43}
"if (1==2) {44}" -> result: if((1 (opfun) 2)) {44}
"if (false == (1 == 2)) {  ((((45)))) }" -> result: if((0 (opfun) (1 (opfun) 2))) {45}
"if (false == (1 == 2)) { if (true) {46} }" -> result: if((0 (opfun) (1 (opfun) 2))) {if(1) {46}}
"if (true == (1 == 2)) {47} else { 48 };" -> result: if((1 (opfun) (1 (opfun) 2))) {47}
Remaining unparsed input: " else { 48 };"
```

---

### Evaluation

All that's left is actual evaluation. The result will be an optional value which could be `optional<int>` for your examples, but I'll make it `variant<Nil, int, bool>` so we can represent conditions as well:

```
namespace Evaluation {
    struct Nil {};
    using Value = boost::variant<Nil, int, bool>;
```

Now the engine is a function object that will be visiting our AST nodes:

```
    struct Engine {
        template <typename... T> auto operator()(T const&... v) const {
            return eval(v...);
        }

      private:
```

Delegating any call to `operator()` to private `eval` methods makes things easier to read, and implementation is pretty straightforward:

```
Value eval(Ast::Expr const& e) const  { return boost::apply_visitor(*this, e); } 
Value eval(int e) const               { return e;                              } 
Value eval(bool e) const              { return e;                              } 
Value eval(Ast::BinOp const& e) const { return e.op(as_int(e.lhs), as_int(e.rhs)); }
```

Here we see the first bit of logic creep in. Since `BinUpF` is `bool(int,int)` we have to coerce the arguments to int.

```
Value eval(Ast::Conditional const& e) const { 
    Value True = true;
    if (eval(e.condition) == True) {
        return eval(e.true_part);
    }

    return Nil{};
}
```

This is where we **finally** answer the meat of your question: the `true_part` is never evaluated if the `condition` evaluates to false¹

### Test #1

Testing the current state of affairs:

```
Evaluation::Engine const eval;

// ...

    if (qi::parse(f, l, parser, expr)) {
        std::cout << "expr: " << expr << "\n";

        try {
            auto result = eval(expr);
            std::cout << "result: " << result << "\n";
        } catch(boost::bad_get const&) {
            std::cout << "result: Type mismatch\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "parse failed\n";
    }
```

Prints **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36143f755dac637b)**

```
result: 0
result: 0
result: 1
result: 42
result: Nil
result: Nil
"false" -> expr: 0
"1==2" -> expr: (1 (opfun) 2)
"-3!=3" -> expr: (-3 (opfun) 3)
"if (true) {42}" -> expr: if(1) {42}
"if (false) {43}" -> expr: if(0) {43}
"if (1==2) {44}" -> expr: if((1 (opfun) 2)) {44}
```

The following expressions fail because the operands aren't integer:

```
"if (false == (1 == 2)) {  ((((45)))) }" -> expr: if((0 (opfun) (1 (opfun) 2))) {45}
result: Type mismatch
"if (false == (1 == 2)) { if (true) {46} }" -> expr: if((0 (opfun) (1 (opfun) 2))) {if(1) {46}}
result: Type mismatch
"if (true == (1 == 2)) {47} else { 48 };" -> expr: if((1 (opfun) (1 (opfun) 2))) {47}
result: Type mismatch
Remaining unparsed input: " else { 48 };"
```

### Three Improvevents

1. Let's allow mixed-type evaluation (`true != false` should also work, right? As well as `true == (1!=9)`.

   Changing the function type from `bool(int,int)` to `Value(Value,Value)` allows for the full gamut.

   ```
   namespace Evaluation {
       struct Nil { bool operator==(Nil) const { return true; } };
       using Value = boost::variant<Nil, int, bool>;

       using BinOpF = std::function<Value(Value, Value)>;
   ```

   For Mixed-Type evaluation we need some help because `std::equal_to` and friends don't know how to do (binary) variant visitation. So, let's make a wrapper for that:

   ```
   template <typename Op> struct MixedOp {
       Value operator()(Value const& lhs, Value const& rhs) const {
           return boost::apply_visitor(Dispatch{}, lhs, rhs);
       }

     private:
       struct Dispatch {
           template <typename T, typename U>
           Value operator()(T const& lhs, U const& rhs, decltype(Op{}(T{}, U{}))* = nullptr) const 
               { return Op{}(lhs, rhs); }

           template <typename... T>
           Value operator()(T const&...) const 
                { throw std::logic_error("Type mismatch " + std::string(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)); }
       };
   };
   ```

   Yeah. That's ugly, but note how it will naturally work for most of the operator functions (like `std::plus<>`, `std::multiplies<>` etc.).

   ```
   // wrap std functionals
   using equal_to     = detail::MixedOp<std::equal_to<> >;
   using not_equal_to = detail::MixedOp<std::not_equal_to<> >;
   using plus         = detail::MixedOp<std::plus<> >;
   using minus        = detail::MixedOp<std::minus<> >;
   using multiplies   = detail::MixedOp<std::multiplies<> >;
   using divides      = detail::MixedOp<std::divides<> >;
   ```
2. Let's also make it so truthy-ness of values is better (`0` should probably just mean `false` like in C, as would `Nil`).

   Let's get the truthyness:

   ```
   namespace detail {
       struct truthy {
           Value operator()(Value const& v) const { return boost::apply_visitor(*this, v); }
           Value operator()(int  v) const { return static_cast<bool>(v); }
           Value operator()(bool v) const { return static_cast<bool>(v); }
           Value operator()(Nil)    const { return Nil{}; }
       };
   ```

   And then define a free function to make it easy to call from our Engine:

   ```
   static inline bool truthy(Value const& v) { return Value{true} == detail::truthy{}(v); }
   ```

   We can now drop the complications from the Evaluation::Engine:

   ```
   Value eval(Ast::BinOp const& e) const { return e.op(eval(e.lhs), eval(e.rhs)); } 
   Value eval(Ast::Conditional const& e) const { 
       if (truthy(eval(e.condition))) {
           return eval(e.true_part);
       }

       return Nil{};
   }
   ```

   No more `as_inst` or `True` comparison.
3. Let's make `else` supported

   This is very simple extending from what we had above. But it will *nicely* demonstrate that only one branch is actually evaluated, e.g. when one branch contains a division by zero.

   ```
   Value eval(Ast::Conditional const& e) const { 
       if (truthy(eval(e.condition))) {
           return eval(e.true_part);
       }
       if (e.false_part) {
           return eval(*e.false_part);
       }

       return Nil{};
   }
   ```

### Full Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c48eb3f5fdd228c)**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

namespace Evaluation {
    struct Nil { bool operator==(Nil) const { return true; } };
    using Value = boost::variant<Nil, int, bool>;

    using BinOpF = std::function<Value(Value, Value)>;

    namespace detail {
        struct truthy {
            Value operator()(Value const& v) const { return boost::apply_visitor(*this, v); }
            Value operator()(int  v) const { return static_cast<bool>(v); }
            Value operator()(bool v) const { return static_cast<bool>(v); }
            Value operator()(Nil)    const { return Nil{}; }
        };

        template <typename Op> struct MixedOp {
            Value operator()(Value const& lhs, Value const& rhs) const {
                return boost::apply_visitor(Dispatch{}, lhs, rhs);
            }

          private:
            struct Dispatch {
                template <typename T, typename U>
                Value operator()(T const& lhs, U const& rhs, decltype(Op{}(T{}, U{}))* = nullptr) const 
                    { return Op{}(lhs, rhs); }

                template <typename... T>
                Value operator()(T const&...) const 
                     { throw std::logic_error("Type mismatch " + std::string(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)); }
            };
        };
    }

    static inline bool truthy(Value const& v) { return Value{true} == detail::truthy{}(v); }

    // wrap std functionals
    using equal_to     = detail::MixedOp<std::equal_to<> >;
    using not_equal_to = detail::MixedOp<std::not_equal_to<> >;
    using plus         = detail::MixedOp<std::plus<> >;
    using minus        = detail::MixedOp<std::minus<> >;
    using multiplies   = detail::MixedOp<std::multiplies<> >;
    using divides      = detail::MixedOp<std::divides<> >;
}

namespace Ast {

    struct BinOp;
    struct Conditional;

    using Expr = boost::variant<
        int,
        bool,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<BinOp>,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<Conditional>
    >;

    struct BinOp {
        Evaluation::BinOpF op;
        Expr lhs, rhs;
    };

    struct Conditional {
        Expr condition, true_part;
        boost::optional<Expr> false_part;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Conditional, condition, true_part, false_part)

namespace Parsing {
    template <typename It>
    struct Expr : qi::grammar<It, Ast::Expr()> {
        Expr() : Expr::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;
            start = qi::skip(space) [ expr_ ];

            simple_
                = '(' >> expr_ >> ')'
                | conditional_
                | int_ 
                | bool_ 
                ;

            auto make_bin = [](auto lhs, auto op, auto rhs) {
                return Ast::BinOp { op, lhs, rhs };
            };

            expr_ %= simple_
                >> *(binop_ >> expr_) [ _val = px::bind(make_bin, _val, _1, _2) ];
            ;

            conditional_
                = lexeme["if"] 
                >> '(' >> expr_ >> ')' 
                >> '{' >> expr_ >> '}'
                >> -(lit("else") >> '{' >> expr_ >> '}')
                ;

            binop_.add
                ("==", Evaluation::equal_to())
                ("!=", Evaluation::not_equal_to())
                ("+",  Evaluation::plus())
                ("-",  Evaluation::minus())
                ("*",  Evaluation::multiplies())
                ("/",  Evaluation::divides())
                ;

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(expr_)(conditional_))
        }

        private:
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Expr()> start;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Expr(), qi::space_type> simple_, expr_;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Conditional(), qi::space_type> conditional_;

        qi::symbols<char, Evaluation::BinOpF> binop_;
    };
}

namespace Evaluation {
    struct Engine {
        template <typename... T> auto operator()(T const&... v) const {
            return eval(v...);
        }

      private:
        Value eval(Ast::Expr const& e) const  { return boost::apply_visitor(*this, e); } 
        Value eval(int e) const               { return e;                              } 
        Value eval(bool e) const              { return e;                              } 
        Value eval(Ast::BinOp const& e) const { return e.op(eval(e.lhs), eval(e.rhs)); } 
        Value eval(Ast::Conditional const& e) const { 
            if (truthy(eval(e.condition))) {
                return eval(e.true_part);
            }
            if (e.false_part) {
                return eval(*e.false_part);
            }

            return Nil{};
        } 
    };
}

namespace Ast { // for debug output only
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, BinOp const& b) {
        return os << "(" << b.lhs << " (opfun) " << b.rhs << ")";
    }

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Conditional const& c) {
        os << "if(" << c.condition << ") {" << c.true_part << "}";
        if (c.false_part)
            os << "else{" << *c.false_part << "}";
        return os;
    }
}
namespace Evaluation { // for debug output only
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Nil) {
        return os << "Nil";
    }
}

int main() {
    Parsing::Expr<std::string::const_iterator> const parser;
    Evaluation::Engine const eval;

    for (std::string const s : {
        "false",
        "1==2",
        "-3!=3",
        "if (true) {42}",
        "if (false) {43}",
        "if (1==2) {44}",
        "if (false == (1 == 2)) {  ((((45)))) }",
        "if (false == (1 == 2)) { if (true) {46} }",
        "if (true == (1 == 2)) {47} else { 48 }",
        // cherry on top:
        "if (false) { 3*3 / 0 } else { 7*7 }", // note division by zero
    }) {
        std::cout << std::quoted(s) << " -> ";

        auto f = begin(s);
        auto l = end(s);
        Ast::Expr expr;
        if (qi::parse(f, l, parser, expr)) {
            std::cout << "expr: " << expr << "\n";

            try {
                std::cout << "result: " << eval(expr) << "\n";
            } catch(std::exception const& e) {
                std::cout << "result: " << e.what() << "\n";
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f!=l) {
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"false" -> expr: 0
result: 0
"1==2" -> expr: (1 (opfun) 2)
result: 0
"-3!=3" -> expr: (-3 (opfun) 3)
result: 1
"if (true) {42}" -> expr: if(1) {42}
result: 42
"if (false) {43}" -> expr: if(0) {43}
result: Nil
"if (1==2) {44}" -> expr: if((1 (opfun) 2)) {44}
result: Nil
"if (false == (1 == 2)) {  ((((45)))) }" -> expr: if((0 (opfun) (1 (opfun) 2))) {45}
result: 45
"if (false == (1 == 2)) { if (true) {46} }" -> expr: if((0 (opfun) (1 (opfun) 2))) {if(1) {46}}
result: 46
"if (true == (1 == 2)) {47} else { 48 }" -> expr: if((1 (opfun) (1 (opfun) 2))) {47}else{48}
result: 48
"if (false) { 3*3 / 0 } else { 7*7 }" -> expr: if(0) {(3 (opfun) (3 (opfun) 0))}else{(7 (opfun) 7)}
result: 49
```

---

¹ Something other than `true`, actually

Comment: [Note: the missing bit is precedence/associativity of the operators. But I didn't want to go there as you only had relational operators to begin with]